# Ignore existing issues in Sonarqube analysis

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am setting up sonarqube code analysis for my existing projects. I want to focus only one issues on new code and ignore already existing issues.Is there a way to export existing defects list and use it as baseline of defects which should be ignored. 
I can create the project and mark all issues as Cannot be fixed/ignored. But i have to do it for every release version. We have different release versions

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, it seems you need to flag some of your Sonar issues, so you can exclude them from results when a new analysis is performed.

You can do it by creating an Action Plan (Important: this feature has been removed from Sonar > 5.3) and assigning the issues to this Action Plan (call it "baseline").

Then, from the Issues view, you can filter by project and Action Plan, selecting all non-baseline Action Plans.

In case you're using Sonar > 5.3 (no Action Plan feature), you can instead add a "baseline" Tag to your baseline issues (do it by bulk-changing them).

Once issues have been tagged, you can (from Issues view) filter by Tag, selecting all existings tags but "baseline" tag, and save this Filter, so you don't need to create it every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the SonarQube Leak Period is for.

You don't mention your SonarQube server version, so I'll assume the latest: 6.3.

Set **Administration > General > Leak > Leak Period** to the appropriate value, whether that's a date, `previous_version`, or a number of days. Then focus solely on "new" metrics, such as Coverage on New Code.

The SonarQube interface is designed to help you focus on Leak Period values by pulling them out into a separate section of the project home page: 
[image]